# ICallHandler, is an interface and cannot be constructed

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, enterprise-library

At code below I got the **error**: *ICallHandler, is an interface and cannot be constructed when resolving the object*

```
            var attributePolicy = new AttributeDrivenPolicy();
            var rulePolicy = new RuleDrivenPolicy("LoggingFlyGoreJumpSleepMethodPolicy", new IMatchingRule[] { new MemberNameMatchingRule(new string[] { "Fly", "Gore", "Jump", "Sleep" }), new AssemblyMatchingRule("Domain") }, new string[] { "LoggingCallHandler", "CounterCallHandler" });
            var interceptor = new InterfaceInterceptor();
            var policies = new InjectionPolicy[] { attributePolicy, rulePolicy };
            var request = new CurrentInterceptionRequest(interceptor, typeof(IMosquito), mosquito.GetType());
            var behaviour = new PolicyInjectionBehavior(request, policies, _container); // *(1) we need a container just to resolve the LoggingCallHandler and CounterCallHandler
            var proxyMosquito = Intercept.ThroughProxy<IMosquito>(mosquito, interceptor, new IInterceptionBehavior[] { behaviour });
            proxyMosquito.Eat();
            proxyMosquito.Sleep();
            proxyMosquito.Suck();
```

I can't get working the RuleDrivenPolicy **but**
if I remove the RuleDrivenPolicy as code below, it runs

```
    var attributePolicy = new AttributeDrivenPolicy();
    var interceptor = new InterfaceInterceptor();
    var policies = new InjectionPolicy[] { attributePolicy };
    var request = new CurrentInterceptionRequest(interceptor, typeof(IMosquito), mosquito.GetType());
    var behaviour = new PolicyInjectionBehavior(request, policies, null); // *(2) container removed
    var proxyMosquito = Intercept.ThroughProxy<IMosquito>(mosquito, interceptor, new IInterceptionBehavior[] { behaviour });
    proxyMosquito.Eat();
    proxyMosquito.Sleep();
    proxyMosquito.Suck();
```

outputing...

```
Mosquito Eating...
Mosquito Sleeping...
LoggingCallHandler Invoking Suck at 12:36:29
Mosquito Sucking...
```

**However**, I want the policy rule to be applied. If the policy rule is applied, the ouptut should be like as if I won't be using the Intercept.ThroughProxy<> method

**Look** the different output of code below, where I use the container to resolve the object instead of getting the object resolved through Intercept.ThroughProxy<> method..

```
 var proxyMosquito = _container.Resolve<IMosquito>();
    proxyMosquito.Eat();
    proxyMosquito.Sleep();
    proxyMosquito.Suck();
```

The ouput is then..

```
Mosquito Eating...
LoggingCallHandler Invoking Sleep at 12:43:07
Mosquito Sleeping...
LoggingCallHandler Invoking Suck at 12:43:08
Mosquito Sucking...
```

The container has the following registrations..

```
+ IUnityContainer '[default]' Container
+ IMatchingRule -> MemberNameMatchingRule 'Member Name Matching Rule-LoggingFlyGoreJumpSleepMethodPolicy' Transient
+ IMatchingRule -> AssemblyMatchingRule 'Assembly Matching Rule-LoggingFlyGoreJumpSleepMethodPolicy' Transient
+ ICallHandler -> LoggingCallHandler 'LoggingCallHandler-LoggingFlyGoreJumpSleepMethodPolicy' ContainerControlled
+ ICallHandler -> CounterCallHandler 'CounterCallHandler-LoggingFlyGoreJumpSleepMethodPolicy' ContainerControlled
+ InjectionPolicy -> RuleDrivenPolicy 'LoggingFlyGoreJumpSleepMethodPolicy' Transient
+ InjectionPolicy 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension.AttributeDrivenPolicy, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Interception, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' ContainerControlled
+ IServiceLocator '[default]' ExternallyControlled
+ IMosquito -> Mosquito '[default]' Transient
+ ExceptionManager '[default]' Transient
+ Database '[default]' Transient
+ ValidatorFactory '[default]' ContainerControlled
```

Here below the basics of the implementation

```
 public class Mosquito : IMosquito
    {

        public void Bit()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Mosquito Biting...");
        }

        public void Eat()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Mosquito Eating...");
        }

        public void Sleep()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Mosquito Sleeping...");
        }

        [LoggingCallHandler(1)]
        public void Suck()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Mosquito Sucking...");
        }
    }

    public interface IMosquito : IAnimal
    {
        void Suck();
    }

    public interface IAnimal
    {
        void Eat();
        void Sleep();
    }

    [ConfigurationElementType(typeof(CustomCallHandlerData))]
    public class LoggingCallHandler : ICallHandler
    {
        public LoggingCallHandler(NameValueCollection attributes)
        {

        }

        public IMethodReturn Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, GetNextHandlerDelegate getNext)
        {
            if (getNext == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("getNext");

            Console.WriteLine("LoggingCallHandler Invoking {0} at {1}", input.MethodBase.Name, DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
            return getNext()(input, getNext);
        }

        public IEnumerable<Type> GetRequiredInterfaces()
        {
            return Type.EmptyTypes;
        }

        public int Order { get; set; }
    }

    public class LoggingCallHandlerAttribute : HandlerAttribute
    {
        private readonly int _order;

        public LoggingCallHandlerAttribute(int order)
        {
            _order = order;
        }

        public override ICallHandler CreateHandler(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            return new LoggingCallHandler(new NameValueCollection()) { Order = _order };
        }
    }

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
  <sectionExtension type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension.Configuration.InterceptionConfigurationExtension, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Interception.Configuration" />
  <container>
    <extension type="Interception" />
    <register type="Domain.IMosquito, Domain" mapTo="Domain.Mosquito, Domain">
      <interceptor type="InterfaceInterceptor" />
      <policyInjection />
    </register>
  </container>
</unity>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="policyInjection" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.PolicyInjection.Configuration.PolicyInjectionSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.PolicyInjection" requirePermission="true" />
  </configSections>
  <policyInjection>
    <policies>
      <add name ="LoggingFlyGoreJumpSleepMethodPolicy">
        <matchingRules>
          <add name="Member Name Matching Rule" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.PolicyInjection.MatchingRules.MemberNameMatchingRule, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.PolicyInjection">
            <matches>
              <add match="Fly" />
              <add match="Gore" />
              <add match="Jump" />
              <add match="Sleep" />
            </matches>
          </add>
          <add name="Assembly Matching Rule" match="Domain" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.PolicyInjection.MatchingRules.AssemblyMatchingRule, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.PolicyInjection"/>
        </matchingRules>
        <handlers>
          <add name="LoggingCallHandler" order="1" type="IoCnAOP.LoggingCallHandler, IoCnAOP" />
        </handlers>
      </add>
    </policies>
  </policyInjection>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what your exact situation is since the container registration code is not shown and I'm not sure where the configuration code comes in.

However, it looks like the issue is in how the call handlers are registered.  The **name** of the call handler (not the class name) is what is passed in to the RuleDrivenPolicy.  You are passing in "LoggingCallHandler" but the container's registration is for "LoggingCallHandler-LoggingFlyGoreJumpSleepMethodPolicy".

If you align the naming then it should work.

```
var interceptor = new InterfaceInterceptor();

var rulePolicy = new RuleDrivenPolicy("LoggingFlyGoreJumpSleepMethodPolicy",
    new IMatchingRule[] { new MemberNameMatchingRule(new string[] { "Fly", "Gore", "Jump", "Sleep" }) },
    new string[] { "LoggingCallHandler-LoggingFlyGoreJumpSleepMethodPolicy" });

var policies = new InjectionPolicy[] { rulePolicy };
var request = new CurrentInterceptionRequest(interceptor, typeof(IMosquito), mosquito.GetType());
var behaviour = new PolicyInjectionBehavior(request, policies, container); 
var proxyMosquito = Intercept.ThroughProxy<IMosquito>(mosquito, interceptor, new IInterceptionBehavior[] { behaviour });
proxyMosquito.Eat();
proxyMosquito.Sleep();
proxyMosquito.Suck();
```

This will show:

> Mosquito Eating...
>   LoggingCallHandler Invoking Sleep at 11:39:35 AM
>   Mosquito Sleeping...
>   Mosquito Sucking...

Showing that Sleep was intercepted since that was the only method we called that we had set a matching rule for.

Also, I was using programmatic configuration and I had to add a default constructor to LoggingCallHandler and tell Unity to use that constructor (since Unity does not know how to resolve NameValueCollection without a registration).  You might not have that issue if using configuration.

Comment: by the way
I am trying to figure out what would be the best workflow for injecting AOP aspects on Entities retrieved  through EF or Enterprise Data.
From a standard repository we get RAW entities, but which is the best workflow for getting them with AOP aspects already applied?
The workflow issues are..
Intercept.ThroughProxy wraps AOP aspects over and existing object or entity, but the result is not a compatible entity since is a proxied entity
Intercept.NewInstance<entity> creates a new entity BUT don’t wrap any existing entity that we would have retrieved from EF or Enterprise Data

Comment: Applying a LINQ conversion to create a new AOP wrapped objects will lead to have the new wrapped objects DETACHED from the EF DbContext 
(for the Data Block doesn’t mind since it don’t have a long running context that keep track of the entities changes)
A valid approach could be to subscribe the ObjectContext public event ObjectMaterializedEventHandler ObjectMaterialized;event that  Occurs when a new entity object is created from data in the data source as  part of a query or load operation and the wrap with AOP aspects the given entity having a derived (but not proxied) compatible entity