# Why am I getting "The current type IDatabaseProvider, is an interface and cannot be constructed." from Unity container?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am getting 2 errors from Unity Container while calling Web API:

> Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.

and

> The current type IDatabaseProvider, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping.

I'm configuring the container using the following XML:

```
<unity>
    <sectionExtension type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension.Configuration.InterceptionConfigurationExtension, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Interception.Configuration" />

    <alias alias="IDatabaseProvider" type="DataAccess.Interfaces.IDatabaseProvider, DataAccess" />
    <alias alias="DatabaseProvider" type="DataAccess.DataAccess.DatabaseProvider, DataAccess" />
    <alias alias="IRepository" type="Repository.BAL.Interfaces.IRepository, Repository.BAL" />
    <alias alias="Repository" type="Repository.BAL.Repository, Repository.BAL" />

     <containers>
        <container name="UnityContainer">
            <register type="IDatabaseProvider" mapTo="DatabaseProvider">
              <lifetime type="singleton" />
            </register>
            <register type="IRepository" mapTo="Repository">
              <constructor>
                <param name="databaseProvider" type="IDatabaseProvider">
                  <dependency name="DatabaseProvider"/>
                </param>
              </constructor>
             <lifetime type="singleton" />
            </register>
        <container/>
     <containers/>
 </unity>
```

And here is my Unity Container code which I have added in Global.asax.cs file:

```
 public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
 {
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        UnityConfigurationSection unitySection = (UnityConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unity");
        IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
        unitySection.Configure(container, 
        unitySection.Containers["UnityContainer"].Name;
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new Unity.Mvc5.UnityDependencyResolver(container));

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);
    }
 }
```

In the controller constructor, I have to call DB which will be one time call. Since Web API constructor is called everytime I set the lifetime of that class as Singleton. I don't want that DB calls everytime the Web API constructor is called.

Below is Web API and Repository class code:

```
public class WebAPIController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IRepository _repository;
    public WebAPIController()
    {

    }

    public WebAPIController (IRepository repository) 
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }
}

public class Repository : IRepository
{
   public Repository(IDatabaseProvider databaseProvider) 
   {
      // This one I want to call only one time even if 
      // Web API controller is called for each request
      var data = databaseProvider.GetAllData();
   }
}
```

Why am I getting this exception about `IDatabaseProvider` being an interface? How do I solve it?

Comment: Show how you register your dependencies in Unity?

Comment: @AzharKhorasany: I have provided the config changes in the question where I have registered the dependencies.

Comment: This line, UnityConfigurationSection unitySection = (UnityConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unity"); where is the 'unity' section in your config?

Comment: @AzharKhorasany: Updated the same. Just added the Unity tags.

Comment: Have a look at this article and see if you have configured everything correctly? https://www.wiktorzychla.com/2011/11/unity-application-block-is-lightweight.html

Comment: @AzharKhorasany: This is the basic example and I have implemented the same in my unity as well but I don't know what is the problem in my case?

Comment: Ok. Basic check then. Is your DatabaseProvider class implements IDatabaseProvider? as this error "The current type IDatabaseProvider, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping" says.

Comment: Ya i have done that  <register type="IDatabaseProvider" mapTo="DatabaseProvider">
              <lifetime type="singleton" />
            </register>

Comment: I've tried to improve your question for you. Also, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31608847/icallhandler-is-an-interface-and-cannot-be-constructed) might be related.

Comment: @TerryR, what I meant was whether your class DatabaseProvider implements IDatabaseProvider in the code? public class DatabaseProvider : IDatabaseProvider { }

Comment: Does it help if you configure your container programmatically?